# How to Solve Int Object is not Subscriptable Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this code (this is only a part of it which was causing the error):

```
 weight_bag_plus = ind_weight_bag + count
                        weight_bag_minus_1 = ind_weight_bag + count - 1
                        ind_plus = weight_bag[weight_bag_plus]
                        ind_plus_minus_1 = weight_bag[weight_bag_minus_1]
                        if  ind_plus < ind_plus_minus_1:
                            count += 1
```

and it gave me this error:

```
Execution failed.
TypeError : 'int' object is not subscriptable

Stack Trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/user_code.py", line 17, in <module>
ind_plus = weight_bag[weight_bag_plus]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I Solve the Error?

Comment: Evidently `weight_bag` is an int, so `weight_bag[weight_bag_plus]` does not make sense. Not knowing what you're trying to do, whatever it is, this is not how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

This means that weight bag is an integer, so you cannot select an index from it or slice it. Ensure that your weight_bag variable is a list, tuple, or dictionary.